# Обновление datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, binding, ado.net, datagridview

Есть схема привязки данных: DataGridView привязана к BindingSource, BindingSource привязан к таблице из DataSet. Также на форме есть Combobox, SelectedValue которого привязан к BindingSource (к конкретной ячейке).

Вопрос в следующем: при изменении значения Combobox отображение в DataGridView меняется, только тогда, когда DataGridView получает фокус. Как это сделать без щелчка на DataGridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это мне не помогло. Сделал через comboBox.Databindings[0].WriteValue(); (это для примера. Может кому понадобится.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте после изменения Combobox делать `DataGridView.Refresh()` или `BindingSource.ResetBindings()`. Но, скорее всего, причина в том, что данные, подключенные к BindingSource, не реализуют INotifyPropertyChanged.

Для более полного ответа нужна информация об отображаемых данных.